# FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow horizontal inactive scrollbar in Firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, overflow, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I am having an issue with my FB Canvas iframe app.
What I use:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    // my app code code code
  });
  FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);
}
```

+ set Fluid width in the app

My issue:

- In Firefox I am getting a horizontal scrollbar (inactive) and I have no idea why.

---

I tried  `overflow: hidden` to html, body.

It seems the FB iframe has an `overflow-x` and because this horizontal scrollbar I am also getting a vertical one, so the setAutoGrow is not behaving normal.

Anyone? any idea or suggestion?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:** seems to be a Firefox issue to show both scrollbars (inactive). The FB iframe gets `scrolling="yes"` causing the scrollbars. Until now I couldn't find a way to target the FB iframe, as the my document is inside it.